# Any Idea How do I Remove This error "Null Check operator used on a null value"

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:taxiapp/models/user.dart';
import 'package:taxiapp/pages/auth/auth_page.dart';
import 'package:taxiapp/repositories/user_repository.dart';
    
    class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
            body: ValueListenableBuilder<User?>(
              valueListenable: UserRepository.instance!.userNotifier,
              builder: (context, value, child) {
                if (value != null) {
                  return Builder(
                    builder: (context) {
                      if (!value.isVerified!) {
                        return AuthPage(page: 2, uid: value.uid);
                      } else {
                        return Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                                'Successfully Logged In \n\n${UserRepository.instance!.userNotifier.value!.email}'),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  return const AuthPage();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

This is where I am getting error

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
valueListenable: UserRepository.instance!.userNotifier,
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

And This my user_repositary.dart

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as auth;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:taxiapp/models/user.dart';

class UserRepository {
  UserRepository._();
  static UserRepository? _instance;

  static UserRepository? get instance {
    _instance ??= UserRepository._();
    return _instance;
  }

  ValueNotifier<User?> userNotifier = ValueNotifier<User?>(null);

  User? get currentUser {
    return userNotifier.value;
  }

  Future<User?> setUpAccount(
      String? uid, String email, String firstname, String lastname) async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).update({
      'email': email,
      'firstname': firstname,
      'lastname': lastname,
      'role': '0',
      'isVerified': true,
    });
    userNotifier.value = await UserRepository.instance!.getUser(uid);
    return userNotifier.value;
  }

  Future<User?> getUser(String? uid) async {
    userNotifier.value = null;
    DocumentSnapshot userSnapshot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).get();
    if (!userSnapshot.exists) {
      return null;
    } else {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = userSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      print(data['email']);
      userNotifier.value = User.fromJson(uid, data);
    }

    return userNotifier.value;
  }

  Future<void> signInCurrentUser() async {
    if (UserRepository.instance!.currentUser == null) {
      auth.User? authUser = auth.FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      if (authUser == null) {
        print("no current user");
        try {
          authUser = await auth.FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().first;
        } catch (_) {}
      }
      if (authUser == null) {
        print("no state change user");
      } else {
        await UserRepository.instance!.getUser(authUser.uid);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Where I am initializing userNotifier as

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
ValueNotifier<User?> userNotifier = ValueNotifier<User?>(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you are using the `!` operator after a nullable variable that is null. Based on the name I'd say it's from the `UserRespository.instance!` in `valueListenable` but it can be any of the other nullable values that you haven't checked for null values.

Comment: Hey I have added one more file please check if there is any way to remove the error

Comment: @SachinV can you also add the error stacktrace? That would be the most help.